# Login using facebook token in quickblox

Tags: php, angularjs, facebook, authentication, quickblox

Here is my code for login in the **Quickblox**

```
  QB.createSession({login: user.login, password: user.pass}, function(err, res) {
    if (res) {
      var user_jid = QB.chat.helpers.getUserJid(user.id, QBApp.appId);
      QB.chat.connect({jid: user_jid, password: user.pass}, function(err, roster) {
        $("#loginForm").modal("hide");

        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(roster);

          QB.chat.onMessageListener = showMessage;

          $('#feed').val('User : CONNECTED at ' + getLocalTime());
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

In the config.js i have two users to chat

```
var QBUser1 = {
      id: 34097xx,
      name: 'andrxx',
      login: 'andrxx',
      pass: 'andrewanxxxx'
    },
    QBUser2 = {
      id: 34098xx,
      name: 'salxx',
      login: 'salxx',
      pass: 'salmasxxxx'
    };
```

This is ok for the regular users.

For the Users logging in using the facebook. I am getting those user's facebook id such as `100005281036919`

I am storing their email, name, login, password field in storing in the user details using regular sign-in call .. like

```
 $http.post('http://api.quickblox.com/users.json', {
        token: quickbloxapitoken,
        user: {
            full_name: firstname,
            email: email,
            login: email,
            password: password
        }
    }, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })
```

The facebook id will be in the login field, i am hardcoding the password field.

**Note :**

As i am wanted to use `angularjs` calls for my project i can't use the native quickblox sample js for login using facebook.

**Now, my question is,**

How can i login those users using only the login and email field.

Or (If not possible)

I can able to give the freshly generated facebook token, facebook id, Is it possible to logged in the which those 2 credentials ?  Or is there anyway to achieve it ?

**Request :**

It may look like off-topic but it was related to  the tag [quickblox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quickblox)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?